# Helm Installation Failed: configMap cannot be handled as a ConfigMap: json: cannot unmarshal bool into Go struct field ConfigMap.data of type string

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Trying to do helm install yet I get an error message like this:

```
install.go:178: [debug] Original chart version: ""
install.go:195: [debug] CHART PATH: /Users/lkkto/Dev/pipelines/manifests/helm/helm-pipeline/charts/base/charts/installs/charts/multi-user/charts/api-service
client.go:128: [debug] creating 4 resource(s)
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: ConfigMap in version "v1" cannot be handled as a ConfigMap: json: cannot unmarshal bool into Go struct field ConfigMap.data of type string
helm.go:84: [debug] ConfigMap in version "v1" cannot be handled as a ConfigMap: json: cannot unmarshal bool into Go struct field ConfigMap.data of type string
INSTALLATION FAILED
main.newInstallCmd.func2
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/install.go:127
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.3.0/command.go:856
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.3.0/command.go:974
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.3.0/command.go:902
main.main
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/helm.go:83
runtime.main
    runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
    runtime/asm_amd64.s:1571
```

Seems like it has to do with my generated configMap:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  DEFAULTPIPELINERUNNERSERVICEACCOUNT: default-editor
  MULTIUSER: true
  VISUALIZATIONSERVICE_NAME: ml-pipeline-visualizationserver
  VISUALIZATIONSERVICE_PORT: 8888
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kubeflow-pipelines
    app.kubernetes.io/component: ml-pipeline
    application-crd-id: kubeflow-pipelines
  name: pipeline-api-server-config-f4t72426kt
  namespace: kubeflow
```

Anything wrong in this?

Comment: can you try wrapping the values of keys under `data:` with double quotes? such as `MULTIUSER: "true"`

Answer (score 20):

From the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/config-and-storage-resources/config-map-v1/#ConfigMap) ConfigMap.data is a `string:string` map. In your example you're setting `MULTIUSER` to a boolean.

Update your ConfigMap to:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  DEFAULTPIPELINERUNNERSERVICEACCOUNT: default-editor
  MULTIUSER: 'true'
  VISUALIZATIONSERVICE_NAME: ml-pipeline-visualizationserver
  VISUALIZATIONSERVICE_PORT: 8888
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kubeflow-pipelines
    app.kubernetes.io/component: ml-pipeline
    application-crd-id: kubeflow-pipelines
  name: pipeline-api-server-config-f4t72426kt
  namespace: kubeflow
```

Notice the `'true'` for `MULTIUSER`. This explicitly sets it to string.

Comment: Thanks, that's the issue. It can be deployed if I set it to 'true'.

Answer (score 3):

Just to buttress more this. Encountered an issue with this when setting up an ingress controller.

My initial config was like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    app: kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus
    heritage: Helm
    release: prometheus
    self-monitor: true
```

The issue was with the `self-monitor: true` which Helm cannot marshall into a string since it's a bool. It should rather be enclosed in quotes like this - `self-monitor: "true"`, so we  will have this afterwards:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    app: kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus
    heritage: Helm
    release: prometheus
    self-monitor: "true"
```