Helm cannot prepare a correct manifest
➜  infra git:(main) ✗ helm secrets -n argocd upgrade --install \
    argocd-apps \
    argo/argocd-apps \
    -f values/argocd-apps.yaml
[helm-secrets] Decrypt skipped: values/argocd-apps.yaml
Release "argocd-apps" does not exist. Installing it now.
Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: unable to decode "": json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field ObjectMeta.metadata.name of type string
Error: plugin "secrets" exited with error

Well, the helm complains about ObjectMeta.metadata.name Let's see what's there.
➜  infra git:(main) ✗ helm secrets -n argocd template \
    argocd-apps \
    argo/argocd-apps \
    -f values/argocd-apps.yaml
[helm-secrets] Decrypt skipped: values/argocd-apps.yaml
---
# Source: argocd-apps/templates/applications.yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: 0
  namespace: argocd

Zero??? Maybe something is wrong in the values?
➜  infra git:(main) ✗ helm secrets decrypt values/argocd-apps.yaml 
applications:
    - name: apps
      namespace: argocd

No, that's right. Why 0?

Maybe this answer may be to any help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72137639/14072498

Thanks @RoarS. , but does not look like it.
The name value must be a string and in my case it is a string.
I tried putting quotation marks, changing the name to numbers, etc., but of course it didn’t help.

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  For this it'd be important to see the Helm template file that produces the Application object you show, and the corresponding fragment of Helm values that's its configuration.  If this isn't code you've written yourself and you're just trying to deploy a prebuilt ArgoCD chart, another site like [devops.se] or [sf] might be a more appropriate place to ask.
